# Analog Audio doesnt work

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, pavucontrol

Just installed 16.04, the front audio jacks don't work. When I looked into Pavucontrol, saw that it was set on Digital Stereo IEC958. Changing it to Analog Output works, except it always says `Headphones (unplugged)`. After 5-10 minutes, it goes back to Digital Audio and Audio stops working. The Rear Jacks work fine, it detects the Line Out fine.

How do I make it detect my headphones?

Comment: This is harware specific.

Comment: Works fine on Windows... (tho I dont wanna go back to it)

Comment: This doesn't mean anything. You need to provide information about your hardware. Do you think that front jack doesn't work on all hardware?

Comment: What info do I need to provide? Please tell me which commands to input